# Heroku SSL Redirection Error

Tags: ssl, heroku

I bought the ssl certificate, added the ssl endpoint, changed the CNAME in my DNS to redirect to the ssl url provided by Heroku

Going to http://thekds.org Redirects me to https://kappa-delta.herokuapp.com **instead of** https://thekds.org. WHY IS THIS???

Answer (score 0):

When you use the SSL:endpoint you can't access the site on the URL assigned to the SSL endpoint so you can't implement a redirect here. You need to have to DNS records CNAME'd to the `herokussl.com` address that was provided when the endpoint was added.

I'll also add, you need to ensure that because you want to use the apex record (ie thekds.org) that you need to use a DNS provider that supports using CNAME records there. DNSimple, DNSmadeeasy, PointDNS to name a few support this record type.

Comment: I use Namecheap and here's what I did: http://i.imgur.com/a4GHSFZ.png?1 . I've spent so much time figuring this out, still no good :(

Comment: who is your DNS hosted with? There are some really bad DNS providers out there that don't validate the record types and then simply say things like "If you set a CNAME record on a @ record you will prevent all other DNS propagating" in their documentation - ahem, EASYDNS!!